# what size of the buffer is sufficient for UDP case of recvfrom?

Tags: c++, udp, multicast

I'm using `recvfrom` to receive udp multicast data. As far as I know it receives not more than 1 datagram in call (is that correct?). What buffer size would be enough for such call then? I guess it should be ~MTU of UDP for this machine, but how can I know it on runtime?

I don't want to "overestimate" size of the buffer because I actually have ring-buffers of buffers under the scene and I don't want to spent too much extra memory.

Comment: I guess it is possible that udp generates fragmentation (http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/udp_user.htm). So, I think your best bet is to allocate a buffer that is equal to the ethernet MTU (1500 bytes) and use the amount of bit read from recvfrom to decide if you need to perform another allocation to finish the read.

Comment: @TomásBadan i don't think UDP can be fragmanted. I either have full datagram or nothing.

Comment: Look in the page that I post before, there you will find an example where UDP fragmentation is got by tcpdump. (3 50.449704 (29.4414)  bsdi.lll6 > svr4.discard: udp 1473 (frag 26304:1480@0+)

Comment: i hope it will not be got by recvfrom :)

Comment: Looking at UDP manual in Linux Programmer's Manual, it says that: "By default, Linux UDP does path MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) discovery.... When turned off, UDP will fragment outgoing UDP packets that exceed the interface MTU...". And it says too: "All receive operations return only one packet.". So, I guess your best bet is an MTU size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of an UDP datagram is 64k. Unless you're allocating a lot of buffers, just use this size.

Comment: it seems that's right. however in my particular case in my particular udp data vendor said that maximum size = ethernet MTU so I've just used 1600 bytes for buffer length.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an *IPv4* UDP datagram *payload* is 65507 bytes, but you won't be getting them other than via the loopback. The best you can do across a real network is the MTU minus 28. The generally accepted practical limit without fragmentation is 534 bytes.

Comment: udp datagram can be fragmmented actually. i.e. delivered in several network packets. so it is possible to sent datagram of 64k over network.

Comment: I can second javapowered. We're using 64k datagrams successfully for UDP multicast over ethernet on Windows and Linux.

Comment: It can be fragmented but it is recommended to avoid this because if you lose one of the fragments you lose the whole packet (and as always with UDP you wont know about it). i.e. it increases the chances of packet loss.